# How to create click events by ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, events, mouse, click

I wanna to create mouse click events by ruby.

left-click, right-click

is there some library to do this?

thanks for your concerns.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want your program to be notified of mouse click events so that it can act upon them, or do you want to inject mouse click events into the windowing system?  And what platform are you on (mac/*nix/Windows/etc)?

Comment: I am using MacOSX. thanks wayne.

Comment: That's good to know--there may not be a platform-gnostic way of dealing with mouse clicks.  What about the other question?  Do you want to inject mouse events into the windowing system for other programs to act upon, or do you want to receive and act upon mouse clicks yourself?

Comment: first suggestion is for me ;)
I want to send my mouse click events into a web browser.

anyway, I got the idea you wanted suggest me ;) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Watir](http://watir.com/).